# What change should I make in my Lead Compensator circuit below to reduce the DC response? Vin be sine wave with variable frequency

Tags: voltage-divider, high-pass-filter

[image]

I want to increase my cutoff frequency, Fc. As Fc=1/2*pi*R*C, Should I reduce the value of either resistor or capacitor to increase my cutoff frequency?

Comment: Lower the capacitor value.

Comment: Lower capacitor value to increase cutoff frequency right? or do you mean to reduce the DC response?

Comment: The DC response is defined by the two resistors and I never mentioned changing them. Lowering the capacitor value pushes up the frequency where the AC response starts to be dominant over the DC response.

Comment: okay. Thank you

Comment: do you wish me to make a formal answer of this?

Comment: That would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

## Schematic

[image]

## AC response

[image]

As C1 gets smaller a 6 dB change in the AC response occurs at a higher frequency. At high frequencies, the gain is unity or 0 dB. At low frequencies, the gain is 50% or -6 dB.

> *What change should I make in my Lead Compensator circuit below to
> reduce the DC response?*

If you want to reduce the DC response you can make R2 smaller or R1 bigger.

Comment: When I was calculating the frequency response of the lead compensator algebraically. I got the following equation
Vout/Vin = √(1+w*R*C) / (4+w*R*C)

Comment: And with the above equation, 
if (omega) w=0
Vout/Vin = 0.5
w>0 & w<0, Vout/Vin = approx 1

Hence the Vout/Vin Vs frequency graph looks like a lag compensator instead of lead compensator

Comment: @PrajaktaBhutkar I can only use the schematic you supplied in your question.